# Prove that the transitive closure of a relation is transitive without using recursion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

In Kunen's book *Set Theory* (from 2013) the transitive closure of a relation $R$ on $A$ is defined as
$$
 R^* = \{ (x,y) \in A^2 : \text{there is an $R$-path from $x$ to $y$} \}
$$
where an $R$-path from $x$ to $y$ simply is a function $s : n+1 \to A$ for some $n \in \omega$ such that $s(0) = x$ and $s(n) = y$ and $s(i) \,R\, s(i+1)$ for all $i < n$.
This is Definition I.9.4 in the book.

Now it is claimed in Lemma I.9.5 that $R^*$ is transitive, the proof being that this is "easily seen by combining paths".

However, I cannot figure out how to combine two paths without appealing to the validity of recursive definitions for $\omega$. The way it is presented in the book somehow suggests that this should be possible.
Indeed, the goal of the chapter really seems to be to prove the recursion principle for well-founded sets without having to prove recursion for $\omega$ first.

Is there a way to combine paths without having to use recursion that I am overlooking?

I would also appreciate if someone could point me to another proof of the principle of well-founded recursion where it is not assumed to already know recursion for $\omega$.

Comment: abcd is a path from a to d.  duvw is a path from d to w.  abcduvw is a path from a to w.

Comment: The basic idea of the proof I've always seen is: define the recursive function to send $x$ to the unique $y$ such that there exists a downward-closed subset of $A$ including $x$ and a partial function $g$ which satisfies the recursive definition on that downward-closed subset and $g(x) = y$.  Then you prove by well-founded induction that this $y$ always does exist and is unique.

Comment: And incidentally, a standard definition of the transitive closure which doesn't reference $\omega$ at all is that $R^*$ is the intersection of all transitive relations on $A$ which contain $R$ as a subrelation.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I think maybe the OP's point is that to formalize that, the most natural formal definition of the composite path would involve the $\le$ relation and a subtraction function, both of which are most naturally defined using recursion on $\omega$.

Comment: I think what's needed to formalize concatenation of paths is the addition function on $\omega$. If $x$ and $y$ are sequences of lengths $m$ and $n$ respectively (considered as functions and thus as sets of ordered pairs), then the concatenation $xy$ is the union of $x$ and the set of ordered pairs $(m+k,y(k))$ for all $k<n$. The addition function is usually defined by recursion, so I don't see a good way to avoid recursion altogether, but you need only this one application of recursion.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: That's how I would have proved this as well. But the book seems to suggest that by avoiding the more standard approach (presented below by @AlbertoTakase) it is not necessary to treat any special cases of recursion first before dealing with the general case. However maybe I'm just misinterpreting what Kunen writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transitive closure of the binary relation $R$ is typically defined to be the following (because it does not require the axiom of infinity)

$$R^{\mathsf{t}}:=\bigcap\{S'\in\mathscr{P}(\mathrm{fld}(R)\times\mathrm{fld}(R)):R\subseteq S'\,\wedge\,S'\circ S'\subseteq S'\}$$

If we allow the axiom of infinity (i.e. the existence of $\omega$) and assume we have proven recursion on $\omega$ then by [Kleene's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_fixed-point_theorem) we have $$\bigcup_{n\in\omega}R_n=R^{\mathsf{t}},$$
where $R_n$ is defined by $R_0=R$ and $R_{n+1}=R_n\cup(R_n\circ R_n)$. This is the other potential definition of the transitive closure. The definition you were provided is somewhat more complex (introducing the notion of paths).

I believe you are correct that induction and recursion on $\omega$ should be assumed if provided the complex definition of the transitive closure. To be precise, what you need is the following result (easily proven by induction) $$\omega=\{n\in\omega:n\sim(n+m)\setminus m\}\qquad(\text{for fixed }m\in\omega)$$
Here $\sim$ is the notion that two sets are equinumerous (i.e. there exists a bijection between the two sets). Of course, recursion is required to define addition $+:\omega^2\to\omega$. With that result, one can easily concatenate two paths.

For a nice exposition of transfinite induction and recursion (without necessarily having the axiom of infinity---I recall the author giving an equivalent formulation of the definition of a binary relation to be well-founded utilizing both the axiom of choice and infinity: "there is no infinitely descending sequence"; this definition is not required and can be forgotten if not interested in the axiom of infinity) see Enderton's Elementary Set Theory Chapter 9. It is the first section titled *Well-Founded Relations*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, also for the reference to Enderton's book. This clearly is the nicer definition of transitive closure.

Comment: Just as a warning: I think for this answer $R$ should be assumed to be a set and not a proper class. Only now I see that I didn't stress in my question that $R$ was supposed to be a class (and actually the problematic case is the one where $R$ is not a set).

Comment: I encourage that you look into ``set-like.'' For example, on this wiki page <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation>. That is essentially what is required to perform transfinite recursion on classes.